# Issue with Custom Cell Rendering in Ant Design Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

In this example, I'm aiming to display a custom component based on the
data in the MembershipData field. However, the result only shows the
field's text content, not the custom component. Any insights into why
the custom rendering isn't working as expected would be greatly
appreciated.  Thank you for your assistance!

```
const columns = [
// ... other columns ...
{
title: "Membership Data",
dataIndex: "MembershipData",
key: "MembershipData",
width: "15%",
render: (text, record) => <div>{record.MembershipData}<div>,
...getColumnSearchProps("MembershipData"),
},
// ... other columns ...
];
```

In this example, I'm aiming to display a custom component based on the data in the MembershipData field. However, the result only shows the field's text content, not the custom component. Any insights into why the custom rendering isn't working as expected would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You need to add the component inside the `<div>` tag and not the text

Comment: i don't get you can you eleborate please

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
render: (text, record) => {
    if (record.MembershipData) {
      return <div><....your component here..../></div>
  }
},
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: does `record.MembershipData` is a boolean?